# Verify that $U + W'$ is also given by $U + W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $U, W$ and $W'$ are all subspaces of $\mathbb F^3$, then if $ U = \{(x, 0, 0) : x \in\mathbb F\}$ and $W = \{(0, y, 0) : y \in \mathbb F$} their sum is equal to
$$ U + W = \{(x, y, 0): x,y \in \mathbb F\}$$
But if $ W' = \{(y, y, 0): y \in \mathbb F\}$, show that $U + W'$ is also given by
$$ U + W' = \{(x, y, 0): x,y \in \mathbb F\}$$
if $U$ is the same as above.

How should I show this? Im a bit confused since for $U + W'$ I would have $(x+y, y, 0)$. Should I somehow show that these two sets are the same and contain the same elements as in $U+W = U+W'$?

Comment: Use that $(x,y,0)=((x-y)+y,y,0).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V=\{(x,y,0):x,y\in F\}$. We show that $U+W'=V$.

"$U+W'\subset V$": For any $(x,0,0)+(y,y,0)=(x+y,y,0)\in U+W'$, clearly we have $(x+y,y,0)\in V$. Hence $U+W'\subset V$.

"$U+W'\supset V$": For any $(x,y,0)\in V$, let $z=x-y$ and we have $(x,y,0)=(z,0,0)+(y,y,0)\in U+W'$.

Thus $U+W'=V$.